How to mock HttpClient using Spock-framework
The following method is providing instances of java.net.http.HttpClient:
@CompileStatic
private static HttpClient getClient() {
    return HttpClient.newBuilder()
            .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_2)
            .connectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
            .build()
}

These instances are used to perform REST-api calls in the same class to a third party site, like this:
final HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString())

I would like to mock these calls so that I can specify the return value, but I cannot figure out how to do it without refactoring the code (which is not an option).
The following does not work (not on HttpClientImpl either) because instance cannot be created.
HttpClient client GroovySpy(global: true)
HttpClient client GroovyMock(global: true)

Overriding the getClient() method is really not an option since there are many injected dependencies that need to be handled.

Maybe this may help you, had a similar problem:
https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.4-SNAPSHOT/interaction_based_testing.html#MockingStaticMethods

Thanks, I will take a look. Seems like a new upcoming feature in the framework but looks promising.

I recommend to refactor the code  under test for better testability, avoiding static methods. Then you do not need any new or special features in the first place. The great thing about BDD is it helps to drive better application design. The test tells you that testing is difficult. Go fix the application code rather than writing a fancier test.

As @Jasha pointed out, the upcoming Spock 2.4 will support static mocking, but for now, you'd have to use a snapshot build.
That being said, I would advise against mocking the HttpClient itself.
This is usually quite awkward to do and can hide important problems.
Instead, I would suggest using a twofold approach. Separate the code that uses the HTTP client into its own class (Communicator). It should only deal with HTTP communication, and any business logic should go into another class (Service) that uses the Communicator.
Test the Communicator using WireMock or MockServer to mock the HTTP server on the other side. This way, you can find actual issues with your HTTP communication.
Test the Service using traditional mocks.
If your code doesn't look like this and you really can't refactor it, I would still suggest going with WireMock or MockServer over plain mocking.
